# Explanations for three clues in a cryptic crossword

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

I've just solved [a cryptic by LR](https://downforacross.com/beta/play/17612) that was originally published on 22 June 2020. My best effort at explaining the clues is below, spoilered in case you want to try the crossword yourself:

> 1A Grandpa gets Centrelink {visit} (3,2) -> POP IN; pop + lINk
>  4A Abandoned fishing gear in {some boxing}? (4,5) -> LEFT HOOKS; ddef
>  9A {Excuse} me after Bali misbehaviour (5) -> ALIBI; (bali)* + I
>  10A Order pain treatment to {seal fate} (9) -> PREORDAIN; (order pain)*
>  11A Thermostat to oscillate when containing {ink}? (7) -> TATTOOS; thermos_tat to os_cillate
>  12A Wikipedia briefly covered Kia recall from {part of Hawaii} (7) -> WAIKIKI; w[(kia)<]iki
>  13A Frank dined with {nominee} (9) -> CANDIDATE; candid + ate
>  15A Southern American has thin middle from {Japanese food} (5) -> SUSHI; S + US + tHIn
>  17A {Idiot} compiler holds cockney's pipe (5) -> **LOSER; ???**
>  19A Yell after Labor's flip-flopping {splurge} (6,3) -> SPLASH OUT; (ALP's)< + shout
>  21A {Result} of coot and emu interbreeding (7) -> OUTCOME; (coot emu)*
>  23A {Expensive car} for Spanish lawyer. The top comes off (7) -> **PORSCHE; ???**
>  24A Half-time comeback! Bravo, sprinting and {hugging}! (9) -> EMBRACING; (tiME)< + B + racing
>  25A {Stadium} starts all rugby events next August (5) -> ARENA; All Rugby Events Next August
>  26A Child's game during beaches' {famines} (9) -> SHORTAGES; shor[tag]es
>  27A Thanks doll, but {not single}! (5) -> TAKEN; ta + ken {the Barbie doll}

> 1D {Pranksters} manufacture lacier jockstrap (9,6) -> PRACTICAL JOKERS; (lacier jockstrap)*
>  2D {Artworks} are plain things without lavish frames (9) -> PAINTINGS; p(-L)ain t(-H)ings {LavisH}
>  3D Debonair obituary featured this {city} (7) -> NAIROBI; debo_nair obi_tuary
>  4D Aloof poets regularly making {strides} (5) -> LOPES; aLoOf PoEtS
>  5D Bob Jane's special offer to {play it by ear} (9) -> FREEWHEEL; ddef {[Bob Jane T-Marts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Jane_T-Marts) is an Australian tyre chain}
>  6D Woman's duck is capturing carbon. {Great feat}! (7) -> HEROICS; her + O + i[C]s
>  7D Woman isn't including {anyone from Muscat} (5) -> OMANI; w_oman i_sn't
>  8D Night in? Nine airs strange {1952 musical} (6,2,3,4) -> SINGIN' IN THE RAIN; (night in nine airs)*
>  14D {Responding} van swerving to lose velocity (9) -> ANSWERING; (-V)an swer(-V)ing
>  16D {Randomly selected} mole examination? (4,5) -> SPOT CHECK; ddef
>  18D {Something to warn} Brazilian city with sensitivity (4,3) -> RIOT ACT; rio + tact
>  20D First strike from Queen against worker - {the butler} (7) -> SERVANT; Strike + ER + V + ant
>  22D {Forbidden} cheers and jeer (5) -> TABOO; ta + boo
>  23D Second thoughts about newspaper {sheets} (5) -> **PAGES; ???**

As indicated above, I'm not sure of the explanations for the following three answers; could you help me out?

- Idiot compiler holds cockney's pipe (5) -> LOSER
- Expensive car for Spanish lawyer. The top comes off (7) -> PORSCHE
- Second thoughts about newspaper sheets (5) -> PAGES

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Idiot compiler holds cockney's pipe -> L('OSE)R.
>  Cockneys often drop their aitches.
>
>  Expensive car for Spanish lawyer. The top comes off -> POR + aSCHE
>  (a reference to [Austin Asche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austin_Asche)), I suppose.
>
>
>  Second thoughts about newspaper sheets -> P(AGE)S
>  PS is *post scriptum* and [The Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Age) is a newspaper.
>
>  It's probably easier to get the last two if you're Australian.

Comment: This surely seems to be the case , I looked up one of the clues ( {Idiot} compiler holds cockney's pipe) and it does appear in the Sydney Morning Herald  ( https://www.smh.com.au/puzzles/crosswords/cryptic/2020-06-22 )  so the point you made about the clues having references to Australian culture/news , it does make sense.

Comment: @Quark-epoch So this puzzle actually appeared in SMH? I'm Singaporean, by the way.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I was throwing stuff around but I looked up one clue and found this, and now that richardB stated about the Australian stuff it just clicked in my head that I saw the hint in SMH when I was looking up the clues

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I am from India but I just picked up on this

Comment: I started to ask how you got LR for compiler, but then I just looked up again at the Q to see that the puzzle was by LR.